# CouchDB - update multiple databases

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I'm quite new to CouchDB... let say that I have a multiple databases in my CouchDB, one per user, each of db have a one config document. I need to add a property to that document across all dbs. Is it possible to update that config document in all databases (not doing it one by one)? if yes what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you should be able to update the document in one database, and then use filtered replication to update the other databases (though you can't have modified the document in those other databases, otherwise you'll get a conflict).

Whether it makes sense for the specific use case, depends. If it's just a setting shared by all users, I'd probably create a shared settings database instead.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that is possible, and I don't think that is the intended use for CouchDB. Even if you have everything in a single database it's not possible to do it in a quick way (there is no equivalent to a SQL update/where statement).

Comment: that's what I was thinking but just wanted to check on a forum, maybe someone got some similar problem. Thx anyway